# Regular Expression using MS Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a text containing words in UPPERCASE followed by a space and then definitions of the word in lowercase. Now I would like to use MS Words Find and Replace to insert a CR before the UPPERCASE word and a TAB directly after the word.

The text looks like this:

LARGE big in size, amount, or number TREATMENT  something that is done to cure someone who is injured or ill ALTERCATION a short noisy argument. WITCH a woman who is supposed to have magic powers, especially to do bad things.

And I would like to convert that to:

LARGE(tab)big in size, amount, or number(CR)
TREATMENT(tab)something that is done to cure someone who is injured or ill(CR)
ALTERCATION(tab)a short noisy argument.(CR)
WITCH(tab)a woman who is supposed to have magic powers, especially to do bad things.(CR)

Sometimes there might be a dot or a comma at the end of the definition.

Thanks!

Comment: [Find and replace text by using regular expressions (Advanced)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f)

Answer (score 1):

Expression to search for: `<([A-Z]@)>`

Expression for replace:   `^p\1^t`

This assumes that only letters A to Z are used in the uppercase words. If they may contain other letters, as in BRONTË and FIANCÉ, add letters inside the brackets, e.g. replacing `[A-Z]` by `[A-ZÉËÈÇÔ]`.

In the “search for” expression, it is crucial that the `<` and `>` delimiters are used, as they match the start and end of a word, respectively. Without them, the expression would match any single uppercase letter separately (since Word does not use “greedy” matching).